# Sheets Auto-populate information based on drop down

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project to make my employees life a bit easier. We're a troubleshooting team, and I would like to create an Excel to direct the support team on what they are going to do. The thing is, I'm not really an expert with Excel or Google sheets. I only know how to create drop-down, and sub drop-down. Basically, here's what I want to happen

Main Category:
Inquiry #1
Inquiry #2

Sub-Category
Sub-Inquiry #1
Sub-Inquiry #1

If a support chooses sub-inqury, a list of steps would be auto-populated in one of the cells. I'm not sure how to make that happen. If I were to do VLOOKUP, I'd think that it'd be pretty hard because I'm going to be putting a lot of steps in 1 single cell.

Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Your question is very vauge. But I assume you want something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mo4COng7Sg

Comment: I believe you're looking for "dynamic dependent drop downs". Search it